# Como devolver un Arraylist en un método Java que recibe parametros

Tags: java

El ejercicio pide que el metodo devuelva a los estudiantes que se encuentran dentro del ArrayList que tengan la misma 'carrera' que se recibe por parametro que es un String.

La clase Estudiante:

```
public class Estudiante {

private int dip;
private String nomb;
private String apel;
private int edad;
private String carrera;
private int tel;
private String email;

        public Estudiante(int dip, String nombre, String apellido,int edad,
                String carrera, int tel, String email)
        {
            this.dip = dip;
            this.nomb = nombre;
            this.apel = apellido;
            this.edad = edad;
            this.carrera = carrera;
            this.tel  =tel;
            this.email = email;
        }

public void mostrar()
{
     System.out.println("Estudiante: "+getNomb()+" "+getApel()+
                            ", "+getEdad()+" años, "+getTel()+", "+getEmail());
}
public int getDip() {
    return dip;
}

public void setDip(int dip) {
    this.dip = dip;
}

public String getNomb() {
    return nomb;
}

public void setNomb(String nomb) {
    this.nomb = nomb;
}

public String getApel() {
    return apel;
}

public void setApel(String apel) {
    this.apel = apel;
}

public int getEdad() {
    return edad;
}

public void setEdad(int edad) {
    this.edad = edad;
}

 public String getCarrera() {
    return carrera;
}

public void setCarrera(String carrera) {
    this.carrera = carrera;
}

public int getTel() {
    return tel;
}

public void setTel(int tel) {
    this.tel = tel;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

}

El metodo a implementar es el siguiente.
PD: este metodo pertenece a otra clase llamada DbUniversidad.

```
public ArrayList<Estudiante> listaEstudiantes(String carrera)
```

Esto es lo que he hecho:

```
public ArrayList<Estudiante> listaEstudiantes(String carrera)
        {
           for(Estudiante e : alum)
            {
             if(e.getCarrera().equals(carrera))
              return alum;
        }
```

Tengo problemas para saber como devolver el arraylist y que solo aparezcan la carrera que se a recibido por parametro. Gracias,

Answer (score 3):

Si estás usando Java 8 en adelante, puedes filtrar los elementos mediante un stream(). El código es el siguiente:

```
public ArrayList<Estudiante> listaEstudiantes(String carrera) {
    // se obtiene la lista de la base de datos en la variable list
    return list.stream().filter(elemento -> carrera.equals(elemento.getCarrera()))
        .collect(java.util.stream.Collectors.toList());
}
```

Si es una versión anterior a Java 8, debes almacenar los elementos filtrados en un arreglo nuevo:

```
public ArrayList<Estudiante> listaEstudiantes(String carrera) {
    ArrayList<Estudiante> resultado = new ArrayList<Estudiante>(); // ahí se almacenan los elementos filtrados por la condición
    // se obtiene la lista de la base de datos en la variable list
    for (Estudiante e : list) {
        if (carrera.equals(e.getCarrera())) {
            resultado.add(e);
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @JoséMaria, estaba atascado.